# How to add a powershell command string in a .bat script?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm creating a .bat script where I need to add a powershell command string.

I know that encoding the script in base64 would work, but for later maintenance it's complicated because I have to undo it all the time.

Here is the .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
mode con: cols=70 lines=20
chcp 65001 >NUL
Title SCCM Client Install
:start
SET choice=
SET /p choice=is there any version of the sccm client installed? (S/[N])? 
IF NOT '%choice%'=='' SET choice=%choice:~0,1%
IF '%choice%'=='S' GOTO sim
IF '%choice%'=='s' GOTO sim
IF '%choice%'=='N' GOTO nao
IF '%choice%'=='n' GOTO nao
IF '%choice%'=='' GOTO sair
ECHO "%choice%" Is not valid option!
ECHO.
GOTO start

:sim
ECHO Uninstalling SCCM Client
POWERSHELL LONG SCRIPT HERE
ECHO.
PAUSE

:nao
ECHO The Client SCCM setups starts
start %~dp0ccmsetup.exe SMSSITECODE=XXX /source:%~dp0
ECHO.
ECHO Running ccmsetup.log
cmd.exe /c "start /min cmd.exe /c "%~dp0CMTrace.exe %systemroot%\ccmsetup\Logs\ccmsetup.log"" >NUL
TIMEOUT 5 >NUL
EXIT

:sair
cls
ECHO OK!
TIMEOUT 2 >NUL
EXIT 0
```

and the powershell script is this:

```
#Stop Services
Stop-Service -Name ccmsetup -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Stop-Service -Name CcmExec -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Stop-Service -Name smstsmgr -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Stop-Service -Name CmRcService -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
#Remove WMI Namespaces
Get-WmiObject -Query “SELECT * FROM __Namespace WHERE Name=‘ccm’” -Namespace root | Remove-WmiObject;
Get-WmiObject -Query “SELECT * FROM __Namespace WHERE Name=‘sms’” -Namespace root\cimv2 | Remove-WmiObject;
#Remove Services from Registry
$MyPath = “HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services”;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\CCMSetup -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\CcmExec -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\smstsmgr -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\CmRcService -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
#Remove SCCM Client from Registry
$MyPath = “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft”;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\CCM -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\CCMSetup -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\SMS -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
#Remove Folders and Files
$MyPath = $env:WinDir;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\CCM -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\ccmsetup -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\ccmcache -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\SMSCFG.ini -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-Item -Path $MyPath\SMS*.mif -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
#Remove ConfigMgr folder in Task Scheduler
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Configuration Manager\" | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false;
schtasks /Delete /TN "\Microsoft\Configuration Manager" /F;
```

Comment: You can always just point to the file.

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: As aside, PowerShell isn't C#, so you can remove all the line ending semi-colons. Also, in a Word document they may look nice, but in code they can do weird things... Use normal, straight quotes instead of those nasty curly thingies

Comment: So far so good, but still, just taking this part of powershell and putting it up there in the .bat file, it still doesn't work, I'm searching here, and I tried a method of grouping all the commands in a single chain using @{} but it still didn't work.